# React Material UI DropDown testing

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, material-ui

How should the second parameter of the React TestUtils.Simulate.change.(MyDropdown, ???) look like to trigger a change, where MyDropDown is a component based on Material UI Dropdown component. If I don't provide any second parameter it looks like it returns a random Hash key instead of the provided MenuItem key.

Comment: The question might be reformulate according to the React TestUtils site like this: How does the eventData dispatched to the onChange event handler of the Materials-ui DropDown component look like?

Comment: Take a look at the below examples. It seems like you may want to avoid passing `eventData`. 

1) [a comment from Paul O'Shannessy](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3151#issuecomment-74943529), a React core contributor: 
"In all of our change related tests, we actually set the value of the DOM node first before simulating the event."

2) Material-UI's own tests follow the same pattern -- set the value, then trigger the change event: [checkbox-spec.js](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/0295fbe38bd39f7047da467fc2772cf17047b092/test/browser/checkbox-spec.js#L54)